# Приведение числа в строку и обратно

Tags: строки, rust

Требуется число (`usize` `isize`) преобразовать в строку(`String` `&str`) и обратно, на языке программирования `Rust`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INT=>STRING**

```
let i = 10000usize;  //IN, TYPE:USIZE
let mut i_str = i.to_string();  //STRING

println!("{}", i_str); //RESULT=> 10000
i_str.push_str("len"); 
println!("{}", i_str); //RESULT=> 10000len
```

**&STR=>INT**

```
let s = "1034";
let mut i = s.parse::<i32>().unwrap(); //IN STR, OUT I32
println!("{}", i); //RESULT=> 1034

i += 1024; 

println!("{}", i); //RESULT=> 2058
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let my_string = "27".to_string();  // `parse()` works with `&str` and `String`!
let my_int = my_string.parse::<usize>().unwrap();
let my_string = my_int.to_string();
```